# How to delete multiple named files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to write a method in Ruby that deletes several named files and directories. Here is my method:

```
def cleanup_all_files
   files = ['*.bat', '*.sh', 'lib/*.jar']
   directories = %w[ data archive report log ]
   files.each do |f|
      File.delete(files[f])
   end
   directories.each do |d|
      FileUtils.rm_rf(directories[d])
   end
end
```

This results in the following error:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Can you post the full error output?

Comment: That is the full error output. Are you saying the above method works for you?

Comment: `FileUtils.rm_rf(directories.concat(files.flat_map {|f| Dir.glob(f)}))`

Comment: Your actual error is `files[f]` and `directories[d]` because `files` and `directories` are `Array` objects and thus they expect an index to be passed to the `[]` method but you are passing `String` objects. [`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Answer (score 4):

`files.each do |f|` already yields the element. Therefore calling `files[f]` does not make sense. But at the same time `File.delete` cannot handle patterns, it expects a specific file names. Find all files matching a pattern with `Dir.glob`:

```
def cleanup_all_files
  file_patterns = ['*.bat', '*.sh', 'lib/*.jar']
  directory_patterns = %w[ data archive report log ]

  file_patterns.each do |p|
    Dir.glob(p) { |f| File.delete(f) }
  end

  directory_patterns do |p|
    Dir.glob(p) { |d| FileUtils.rm_rf(d) }
  end
end
```

Comment: `File.delete(*Dir.glob(p))` also works, but your choice of using `glob` with a block has the advantage that no temporary array (`Dir.glob(p)`) is constructed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland well close except `Dir#glob` isn't being called with a block so the `Array` is still created and then iterated with `each`. Also @spickerman you have `each do {}` which seems like a syntax error if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @engineersmnky, I only see what I want to see.  spikermann,  you don't want `do` to precede `{`, but you can also drop `.each`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland and @engineersmnky for pointing out the syntax error. I fixed my answer. But I will keep the `Dir.glob(p).each { |f| File.delete(f) }` instead of using `File.delete(*Dir.glob(p))` because I think that is closer to what the OP already had and therefore makes it more obvious why the OP's version does not work.

Comment: I meant you could simplify to `Dir.glob(p) { |f| File.delete(f) }`.